# How to add Page URL link in footer magento2

Tags: magento2

I am trying to add new link in footer using CMS block and I know how to do that.first create new block in admin then go to your theme's layout->default.xml file and add below code so it will show link in Front end footer section.

```
<referenceContainer name="footer">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="Our Store">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Our Story</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">Our Story</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```

Now I have one problem is that which path I need to assign so when I click on this link it go to my Block's contain.

```
 <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">Our Story</argument>
```

on the above code what I need to specify or replace `Our Story`? so when I click on `Our Story` I go to this block's contain that I add in admin.right now I am getting 404 page not found.

Comment: check the path you gave and the cms page url key is same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the path you gave and the cms page url key is same!

You are getting 404. So your cms page url key is not same as path!